# Running supervisord on a read only filesystem

Tags: supervisord

I'm trying to run `supervisord` on a read only filesystem.

I have tried to stop `supervisord` from writing log and pid files using the following configuration:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
user=root
logfile=/dev/stdout
logfile_maxbytes=0
pidfile=/dev/null
```

However, when I attempt to start, I still receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/supervisord", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('supervisor==3.3.4', 'console_scripts', 'supervisord')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor/supervisord.py", line 349, in main
    options = ServerOptions()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor/options.py", line 428, in __init__
    existing_directory, default=tempfile.gettempdir())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 275, in gettempdir
    tempdir = _get_default_tempdir()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 217, in _get_default_tempdir
    ("No usable temporary directory found in %s" % dirlist))
IOError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/']
```

Is it possible to start/run `supervisord` on a read only filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `TEMPDIR` environment variable to a rw volume mount.

Comment: Actually TMPDIR